# Get value from the user selected option on select option element and update the input form based on chosen option

Tags: jquery, contact-form

I want to update the form once the user selects why they want to contact me with so I can get the relevant information from them, I have this at the moment;

==== HTML ====

```
<select name="Reason" id="Reason" required>
         <option value="" disabled selected>Select Option</option>
         <option value="Please give me a price" >Price</option>
         <option value="I have some positive feedback">Postive Feedback</option>
         <option value="I have some negetive feedback">Negetive Feedback</option>
         <option value="I have a suggestion">Suggestion</option>
         <option value="Other">Other</option>
 </select>
```

I tried using JQuery to get the value or the text selected from the option select (i don't mind which). I managed to get an alert box to appear once the value had changed by using .change() function but couldn't get the value of the selected option to appear or to print out some sort of way to find out if one or another option had been selected.

==== JQuery ====

```
var selectedOption = $("#reason option:selected").text()

reason.change(checkValue);

function checkValue(){
    alert(selectedOption);
}
```

I just want some input textfields to appear if 'Price' is selected, and if anything else is selected just a multiline text area to appear.

Comment: Is the variable `reason` defined somewhere? (`reason.change(checkValue)`).

Comment: yes is is 'var reason = $('#Reason');' like so

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this, is that? specially answered for:

*I just want some input textfields to appear if 'Price' is selected, and if anything else is selected just a multiline text area to appear.*

```
$("#textBoxes").hide();
$("#textAreas").hide();

$("#Reason").change(function(){
    if(this.value == "Please give me a price"){
         $("#textBoxes").show();
         $("#textAreas").hide();
    }
    else{
         $("#textAreas").show();
         $("#textBoxes").hide();
    }
});
```

#### Fiddle Demo

Comment: I had a go at doing this, i added a text field on the page for a demo. my code isnt inline if this make a difference

on loading the message and text box fields hide but they do not reappear upon selecting an option

Comment: @user2568418 Ok.. can you update my fiddle and give more idea how you wanted to show your textboxes or textareas?

Comment: would it make a difference if the JQuery is inline code or from another document?

Comment: Yes, it will because we are using static ids so better to write it inline for now

Comment: Thats brilliant, it works now. Just one thing though, i assume if i set these fields to 'required' the form wont submit? do you know away around this?

Comment: @user2568418  You can set validation using `$("#form1").validate()` [Brief Description about form validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the value of the selected option inside your handler, otherwise the variable won't be updated with the current value. Also, jQuery selectors are case sensitive, so you'll need to use `#Reason` not `#reason`.

This should work for you:

```
$('#Reason').on('change', function(){
    var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    alert(selectedOption);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axtzF/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code like this:

```
$('#Reason').change(checkValue);

function checkValue(){
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CEsBK/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
$('#reason').on('change', function(){
    //pick your poison
    alert($(this).val());
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').html());
});
```

Good Luck!